# Protractor Issue with spec.js files being updated, but not running

Tags: javascript, protractor

Can't find a solution anywhere for this problem.

Basically I've created a set of tests in protractor, ran and built them locally. Now I'm trying to test them on our staging server, so have pointed all the URL's to the new site for the spec.js files to use, here's the problem, the spec.js files are loading code that no longer exists!

Here's an example

[image]

Now notice the sendPassword variable, the error that I'm getting is from the old locator used by that element, I've searched the entire project and that selector isn't used. It was used, but has been changed to the new sendPassword.

[image]

The most bizarre of all is when I change the urls to point back to my local machine I don't get this error!

I've tried updating webdriver, restarting the system, I just don't understand why it won't recognize the changes made to not only this spec, but a couple others.

Comment: Where are you providing the url? Also instead of screenshot.. can you update the question with code .. Also I would suggest adding code of the spec along with page class

Comment: sure I'll upload that now, I provide the urls in the conf.js file.

Comment: Do you control the url from `browser.baseUrl` parameter?

Comment: no I just created a urls: {} object which contains the urls, they are then called by the spec files.

Comment: **the spec.js files are loading code that no longer exists!**, Are you using Jenkins / some other CI tool to build the project? Does the right git hub branch has been used to build the project?

Comment: Hey yeah I figured it out last night!, if you provide as answer I can select it.